# WordPress wp get nav menu items does not deliver external link

Tags: menus

When I read the nav items per wp get nav menu items the get_page_link( $id ) or `$item->url` does not give me the external URL I entered: http://www.mydomain.com.

Instead I seem to get http://www.mydoamin.com/wordpress/NameOfMenuItem

Any ideas?

I'm using permalinks and thought this might be the problem?

This is the menu code:

```
<?php
```

function bfShowHideMenu($menu_name, $args=array()) {

```
// Klassen von außen bestückbar
$bfListClass = "no-bullet bfZ1000";
$bfItemClassLevel1 = "";
$bfItemClassLevel2 = "";
$bfLinkClass = "navitem";
$bfContainerClass = "subScrollNavi";

$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
$menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id );

echo '<ul class="' . $bfListClass . '">';

$count = 0;
$submenu = false;

foreach( $menuitems as $item ):
    // get page id from using menu item object id
    $id = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );
    // set up a page object to retrieve page data
    $page = get_page( $id );
    //$link = get_page_link( $id );
    $link = $item->url;

    // item does not have a parent so menu_item_parent equals 0 (false)
    if ( !$item->menu_item_parent ):

        // save this id for later comparison with sub-menu items
        $parent_id = $item->ID;

        // Hat der Knoten Kinder?
        $hasChildren = false;
        foreach( $menuitems as $child ){
            if ($child->menu_item_parent == $parent_id) {
                $hasChildren = true;
                break;   
            }
        }
        echo '<li class="';
        if ($hasChildren) echo "bfSHTrigger";
        echo ' ' . $bfItemClassLevel1 . '">';

        echo '<a href="' . $link . '" class="' . $bfLinkClass . '">';
            echo mb_strtoupper($page->post_title);
        echo '</a>';

    endif;

    if ( $parent_id == $item->menu_item_parent ):

        if ( !$submenu ): 

            $submenu = true;

            echo '<div class="bfSHContainer bfSHSubScrollNavi ' . $bfContainerClass . '">';
            echo '<ul class="' . $bfListClass . '">';  
        endif;

        echo '<li class="' . $bfItemClassLevel2 . '">';
        echo '<a href="' . $link . '" class="' . $bfLinkClass . '">' . mb_strtoupper($page->post_title) . '</a>';
        echo '</li>';

        if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu ):

            echo '</ul>';
            echo '</div>';

            $submenu = false; 
        endif;

    endif;

    if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id ):
        echo '</li>';

        $submenu = false; 
    endif;

    $count++; 
endforeach;

echo '</ul>';
```

}
?>

Comment: please add the code you are using to the question.

Comment: Hi, should have done that from the beginning. Edited the post.

Answer (score -1):

For some reason when I use $link = $item->url now it works.
Instead of $link = get_page_link( $id ).